# Extract P values from coxph

Tags: r

I run the following code and get an object names res.cox, which when I print I can see its p values

```
res.cox <- coxph(
  Surv(DB$time,DB$event) ~
    age + gender + var1 + var2 + ... + varN
  , data =  DB)
```

i can easily extract the HR and the Conf interval by the following:

```
HR <- round(exp(coef(res.cox)), 2)
CI <- round(exp(confint(res.cox)), 2)
```

But whatever I try I can't extract the list of P values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `broom::tidy(res.cox)` and `glance`. Using base R `summary(res.cox)[['coefficients']][,'Pr(>|z|)']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the statistics including the *p* value isn't yet available until a `summary()` method is called. (Calling `res.cox` directly yields a *p* value, but probably there's an invisible `summary` call involved.)

## Example

```
library(survival)
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1)
```

Looking into the `str()`ucture reveals that there are only the betas but no statistics.

```
str(res.cox)
```

Whereas in the `summary()` they are available in the `"coefficients"`.

```
str(summary(res.cox))
```

So let's get'em.

```
res.cox.sum <- summary(res.cox)$coefficients
```

The object you get is a `"matrix"`, and, thus, can be treated like that.

```
class(res.cox.sum)
# [1] "matrix"
```

Since the desired *p* value is in the fifth column, do:

```
res.cox.sum[, 5]
# [1] 0.3292583
```

Or short:

```
summary(res.cox)$coefficients[, 5]
# [1] 0.3292583
```

## Data

```
test1 <- structure(list(time = c(4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), status = c(1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0), x = c(0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), sex = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need HR, CI and P value, I have used `broom::tidy` to put them together into a data frame for a table or graph presentation:

```
library(survival)
mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x1 + x2, df) 
mod0 <- broom::tidy(mod)
term <- HR <- lb <- ub <- p <- vector()
for (i  in 1:2) {
  term[i] = mod0$term[i]
  HR[i] = mod0$estimate[i]
  lb[i] = mod0$conf.low[i]
  ub[i] = mod0$conf.high[i]
  p[i] = mod0$p.value[i]
} 
outcome <- data.frame(term, HR, lb, ub, p)
outcome
```

```
  term        HR         lb       ub         p
1   x1 0.7547319 -0.9071983 2.416662 0.3734241
2   x2 0.1931036 -0.4794228 0.865630 0.5735932
```

### Data

```
df <- list(time = c(4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
           status = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), 
              x1 = c(0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
              x2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```